# Changing a struct inside another struct in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, struct, foreach

The following code prints (when invoking MyMethod):

```
0
0
0
1
```

I would expect it to print:

```
0
0
1
1
```

Why is this?

Code:

```
private struct MyStruct
{
    public MyInnerStruct innerStruct;
}

private struct MyInnerStruct
{
    public int counter;

    public void AddOne()
    {
        ++counter;
    }
}

public static void MyMethod()
{
    MyStruct[] myStructs = new MyStruct[] { new MyStruct() };

    foreach (var myStruct in myStructs)
    {
        MyStruct myStructCopy = myStruct;

        Console.WriteLine(myStruct.innerStruct.counter);
        Console.WriteLine(myStructCopy.innerStruct.counter);

        myStruct.innerStruct.AddOne();
        myStructCopy.innerStruct.AddOne();

        Console.WriteLine(myStruct.innerStruct.counter);
        Console.WriteLine(myStructCopy.innerStruct.counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this behavior has to due with using an iteration variable.  Iteration variables are read-only in the sense that in C# you cannot modify them (C# lang spec section 8.8.4 details this

> The iteration variable corresponds to a read-only local variable with a scope that extends over the embedded statement

Playing with read-only mutable structs is a path to unexpected behavior.  Instead of using the variable directly you are actually using a copy of the variable.  Hence it's the copy that is getting incremented in the case of `myStruct` and not the actual value.  This is why the original value remains unchanged.

Eric did a rather in depth article on this topic that you can access here

- http://ericlippert.com/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/

Yet another reason why you should **always** have immutable structs.

Comment: Nice, that was the blog I was looking for :)

Comment: Doesn't this explanation raise another question? If myStruct is readonly (which I'd expect it to be) then surely myStruct.InnerCopy.AddOne() should fail by throwing an exception. If you can call a non-const method (as we'd call it in the C++ world) on a const / read-only object and have it silently do nothing rather than complain, there's surely something very wrong...

Comment: AAT, what happens here is that the mutating method is called on a mutable *copy*. Value types are COPIED BY VALUE, that's why they're called "value" types. If you don't want stuff to be copied by value, then don't use value types.

Comment: @AAT C#'s read-only and the C++ concept of const are **very** different constructs.  In C++ it's an attempt to ensure a single value is not unexpectedly mutated.  In C# read-only when applied to value types causes a copy of the value to be created whenever it is used (or at least when a member is accessed) thus preventing mutation of the original value.  I'm hesitant to say much further because I don't deeply understand all of the circumstances under which C# ensures of value of the struct is returned.  Hopefully Eric will be along in a bit to give a more thorough answer.

Comment: Indeed, Jared, your explanation is correct. Unfortunately, we do not *strictly* ensure that so-called "read only variables" like the "foreach" and "using" variables eare treated *exactly* the same way that we treat readonly fields; it is *possible* to abuse certain compiler behaviours (involving closure rewriting) to induce mutations in such variables of mutable value types. I consider these behaviours to be compiler bugs, but the scenarios are obscure and the spec is imprecise. Hopefully we'll fix those up in a hypothetical future release.

Comment: @JaredPar - thanks for the explanation, that's just another one to put on my list of C# gotchas...

Comment: @AAT: Do you actually have such a list? If so, I would love to see it.  We are always looking for ways to eliminate or mitigate "gotcha" scenarios.

Comment: @EricLippert It's great that you have migrated all the blog posts to your new blog and updating links to them. However, I found that the comments on your MSDN blog also had lot of great insights. Do you have any plans to migrate them? If you want, I can write a scrapper to copy those comments from MSDN blog and create a import script for WordPress. Let me know.

Comment: @SolutionYogi: That is very kind of you! I have considered doing that but I haven't had the time to do so. Tell you what, if I do decide to do that, I'll ask you for assistance because wordpress scripting is not exactly one of my areas of expertise.

Comment: @EricLippert I have had a decent success as a software developer (still lots to learn) and I attribute it to the knowledge and insight shared by you and Joel Spolsky. I think I would have been a very mediocre developer (and I won't even know it) if you did not write those wonderful articles. You are a great teacher and this will be my way of saying thank you. Let me spend sometime on weekend and see if I can write something quickly, shouldn't be too hard thanks to C#! :)]

Answer (score 1):

Iterations variables are read-only, and one would normally be forbidden from modifying a read-only structure directly, or passing such a structure or any part thereof by `ref` to any code which would modify it.  Unfortunately, there's a wrinkle: even though many struct methods and properties don't mutate the underlying structure, calling a method or property on a structure requires that it be passed by `ref` whether or not the method or property will alter the struct instance.  This left the designers of C# with five choices:

1. Don't allow struct methods or properties to be used on structures in read-only context without explicitly copying the structs to a mutable storage location (most likely a local variable).

   Allow struct methods or properties to be used on structures in read-only context, and hope that they won't modify anything they're not supposed to.

   When calling a method or a property on a read-only struct, silently make a copy of the struct and give that copy to the method or property.

   Provide a means by which struct methods or properties can indicate declaratively whether or not they will mutate the underlying structure; only allow struct methods and properties to modify their own fields if they are declared as doing so, and only allow read-only structs to be passed to methods which are not declared as modifying them.

   Provide a means by which struct methods or properties can indicate declaratively whether or not they will mutate the underlying structure; forbid the use of such methods and properties on structures in read-only contexts, but make a defensive copy of read-only structures when calling methods without such declarations just in case the methods should have them but don't.

Choice #1 would be a little annoying, especially with regard to structs that expose their state via properties.  Choice #2 or #4 would be good from a performance standpoint, but struct routines which unexpectedly write `this` could cause unexpected behavior.  Microsoft opted for #3 (choice #5 would be the same except for the addition of optional attributes).  In many ways, that's the worst choice (methods which don't write `this` will run slower than they would without the copy operation, methods which do write `this` won't work correctly with or without it, and the only thing damaged when a struct writes a read-only variable would be an instance of a struct whose code was already broken).  Nonetheless, that choice is by now well established, and it is what it is.

Incidentally, even read operations structures nested within readonly structures or properties of structure type can be much more expensive than using non-read-only fields but simply refraining from writing them.  When calling `myStruct.innerStruct.AddOne()`, the compiler first makes a copy of `MyStruct`, and then makes a copy of `myStruct.InnerStruct`, and then calls the `AddOne()` method on that.  By contrast, when calling `myStructCopy.innerStruct.AddOne()`, it can pass `innerStruct` by reference to the `AddOne()` method without copying anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that the MyStruct.innerStruct actually returns a copy of the struct, and not the struct itself. Therefore you're increasing the value of the copy...

Sure I read a blog about this recently somewhere.

If you change the following

```
myStruct.innerStruct.AddOne();
Console.WriteLine(myStruct.innerStruct.counter);
```

to

```
MyInnerStruct inner = myStruct.innerStruct;
inner.AddOne();
Console.WriteLine(inner.counter);
```

Then you should see it start working.

Comment: But why does the myStructCopy get its counter increased?
My best guess is that is has something to do with myStruct being readonly.